# LDAPs query for cross domains in AD forest trust

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I have two domains(DomainA and DomainB) each in their own AD forests and I have established a forest trust between them,. I am now trying to connect and bind to DomainA and query DomainA for certain attributes of a DomainB user, which is basically a cross domain query.

I am using DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection and I have set the port to be 636(SSL port) and set the Referral Chasing to ReferralChasingOption.All in C# code. Yet, when the code executes to search the response, I see this error message -
"A referral was returned by the server"

```
private static LdapConnection getLdapsConnection()
{
        LdapConnection connection;
        LdapDirectoryIdentifier identifier;
        NetworkCredential credential;
        try
        {
                credential = getAdminCredential();
                identifier = new LdapDirectoryIdentifier("DomainA.local", 636);
                connection = new LdapConnection(identifier, credential)
                {
                        AuthType = AuthType.Basic,
                        SessionOptions =
                        {
                                ProtocolVersion = 3,
                                SecureSocketLayer = true,
                                VerifyServerCertificate = new VerifyServerCertificateCallback(true)
                        }
                };
                connection.SessionOptions.ReferralChasing = ReferralChasingOptions.All;

                return connection;
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
                return null;
        }
}


public static SearchResponse retrieveUserAttributes(string userName(DomainB_User), List<string> attributesToReturn, LdapConnection connObj)
{
        try
        {
                String filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=" + userName + "))";
                String target = "CN=userName,CN=Users,DC=DomainB,DC=local";
                SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(target, filter, System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchScope.Subtree, attributesToReturn.ToArray());
                SearchResponse response = (SearchResponse)connObj.SendRequest(searchRequest);
                return response;
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
                return null;
        }
}
```

Not sure why the referral error is seen even though referral chasing option is set.

Note:
The same code works perfectly fine for LDAP over 389, this is an issue only for LDAP over ssl for cross domain

Comment: Do both domains support ldap over ssl (certificates, firewall rules are configured)? For the test purposes you can disable referral chasing and connect to dc in domainA (query user in this domain) then connect to a dc in domainB (query user) with your code

Comment: @oldovets, thanks for replying. Yes, all rules in place, certificates imported and no network connectivity issues.
Same domain LDAP and LDAPs queries work.
and Cross domain LDAP queries work, the issue is with cross domain LDAPs

Comment: Ok, in this case I use algorithm, which is called: what can go wrong with Microsoft tool. I believe ldp.exe suits here. Need to run it with the same query parameters to check if it can perform ldap query (on the same computer, under the same account, connect to the same dc) via ssl and chase referrals. Please reply with the results

Comment: @oldovets, yes, we did use the ldp.exe tool to verify.
The AD forest trust config has no issue, verified the cross domain queries with the same query parameters against ldp.exe tool, they work fine with referral chasing enabled.

Comment: Nice. Now need to find the difference between your code and what ldp.exe actually does. There should be a difference with ldap session options passed to the query. To find that difference you can use one of two options: connect ldp.exe via 389 port with referral chasing and use network sniffer or use api hook (I prefer Api monitor) that will show you ldp.exe ldap api calls with arguments passed

Comment: I will be having access to active directory environment on Monday, so can help you with api monitor if you will be in trouble at that time